# Why is the 'arguments' property on the function object null?

Tags: javascript, arguments

Code:

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
    console.log('hi');
}

console.log(foo);
```

Output:

(expanded)

```
foo(a, b, c)
    arguments: null
    caller: null
    length: 3
    name: "foo"
    prototype: Object {...}
    <prototype>: function()
```

Question:

Looking at the function's properties, most of them make sense:

- caller is null because I called foo(); on the global object
- name is "foo" because of the function's definition
- length is the number of arguments

But why is arguments returning null? How can we populate that list?

EDIT: I am not talking about the properties of what `foo()` returns. I am talking about the properties of the function object `foo` itself.

To clarify:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTiiu.png)

Comment: "*caller is null because I called foo(); on the global object*" - uh, no, in the code you posted `foo()` is not **called** at all, it's just being logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Function.prototype.arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) property is only available inside the function when while it (or some invocation of that function) is running, but it's deprecated, so you shouldn't use it:

```js
function foo(a, b, c) {
    console.log('hi');
    console.log(foo.arguments);
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Instead, use the standalone `arguments`, or (preferably) rest syntax and check its `.length` to see how what sort of arguments were passed:

```js
function foo(...args) {
    console.log(args);
}

foo(1, 2);
```

(It still only makes sense to check the arguments while the function is running)

Comment: "*only available inside the function*" - well, no, the whole problem with it is (was) that it is available outside of the function scope as well